# Riemann's Trick with Hankel Contour

Tags: contour-integration, riemann-zeta

I was reading a paper about analytic continuation of the Riemann $\zeta(s)$ function and stop in a step that I don't understand:

$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{ s -1} }{e^{x}-1} \,dx = \prod(s-1).\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{1}{n^s}$$

Here it says that it took the countour Integral:
$$\int_{+\infty}^{+\infty} \frac{(-x)^{s} }{e^{x}-1} \,\frac{dx}{x}$$

And with that integral, use the countour from $+\infty$, around the origin, and going back to $+\infty$
(according to what I understand, this is a Hankel Contour)

Then, the integral is splitted in 3 parts (from the inf to origin, circle, and back to inf) and the reasoning continues...

Can anyone explain the purpose of this "trick"? What is the purpose of splitting the integral like that?

Why the contour is chosed like this?

Please help me, I am desperate

Comment: Are you familiar with complex analysis?  A Hankel contour is the limit of keyhole contours which pick up the poles and corresponding residues of the integrand at $x=k2\pi i$ for $k \in \mathbb{Z}\setminus\{0\}$.

Comment: Tom Copeland gives a good reasoning in his answer to [this MO-question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/58004/how-does-one-motivate-the-analytic-continuation-of-the-riemann-zeta-function/97401#97401).

Comment: If you read french everything is detailed [there](https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonction_z%C3%AAta_de_Riemann#Par_une_int%C3%A9grale_de_contour)

Comment: @dzoooks I understand the contour but not figuring out why Its using it, or the purpose of using such curve.
@ dietrichBurde thank you I will chek the link
@ reuns, maybe I will translate it and see If there is a good explanation over there.
Thank you people

Answer (score 6):

For $\Re(s) > 0$
$$\Gamma(s) = \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx$$
For $\Re(s) > 1$
$$\int_0^\infty \frac{x^{ s -1} }{e^{x}-1} \,dx = \sum_{n=1}^\infty \int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-nx}dx=\sum_{n=1}^\infty n^{-s}\int_0^\infty x^{s-1}e^{-x}dx= \zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$$

With $C$ the contour following $(\infty,0]$ then enclosing $0$ then following $[0,\infty)$ we get
$$\int_C \frac{x^{ s -1} }{e^{x}-1} \,dx = \int_\infty^0 \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^{x}-1}dx+\int_0^\infty \frac{(e^{2i\pi}x)^{s-1}}{e^{e^{2i\pi} x}-1}d(e^{2i\pi}x)= (e^{2i\pi (s-1)}-1)\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)$$

The point is that (from the Cauchy integral theorem) we can move contours for integrals of analytic functions, thus we can replace $C$ by a contour $\mathcal{C}$ enclosing $[0,\infty)$ clockwise but not passing through $0$ obtaining 
$$(e^{2i\pi (s-1)}-1)\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)=\int_\mathcal{C} \frac{x^{ s -1} }{e^{x}-1} \,dx$$

> The latter integral converges for all $s$ and is an entire function of $s$

Finally for $\Re(s) < 0$ we can close the contour by adding an infinitely large circle and apply the residue theorem $$(e^{2i\pi (s-1)}-1)\zeta(s)\Gamma(s)=\int_{\mathcal{C}\cup |x|=\infty} \frac{x^{ s -1} }{e^{x}-1} \,dx$$ $$ = 2i\pi \sum Res(\frac{x^{ s -1} }{e^{x}-1}) = 2i\pi \sum_{k \ne 0} (2i\pi k)^{s-1}=(2i\pi)^s (1+(-1)^{s-1})\zeta(1-s)$$
The whole thing is the first step of Riemann's 1859 extraordinary paper.