# Riemann's integral used as an analytic continuation of $\zeta(s)$

Tags: improper-integrals, riemann-zeta, analytic-continuation

In the Riemann's paper "[On the Number of Primes Less Than a Given Magnitude](http://www.claymath.org/sites/default/files/ezeta.pdf)" we have $\zeta(s)$ defined for $\Re(s)>1$ by this integral:

$$\tag{1}\zeta(s)=\frac{1}{\Gamma(s)} \int_0^{\infty } \frac{x^{s-1}}{e^x-1} \, dx$$

Then he considers the following integral:

$$\tag{2}\int_{\infty}^{\infty} \frac{(-x)^{s-1}}{e^x-1} dx$$

with explanation what path of integration he meant - depicted on the picture:

[image]

His motivation was to obtain a formula for $\zeta(s)$ that would be valid for all complex values of $s$.

**1.** But what was the reason behind choosing this particular integral $(2)$ that differs from $(1)$ only in replacing $x$ with $(-x)$ in one place?

**2.** And what was the reason to choose the particular integration path?

**3.** How is it evident that the new integral should be convergent in the whole complex plane?

Comment: I suggest looking into Edwards's book on the subject as the author does a lot of speculation on Riemann's motives and reasoning, including about what you ask;

Comment: All you can read about convergence of integral $(2)$ in Edwards book is: "However, formula for $\zeta(s)$ remains valid for all $s$. In fact, since the integral in (2) clearly converges for all values of $s$, real or complex (because $e^x$ grows much faster than $x^s$ as $x\to \infty$." He argues as if we do not have the same $e^x$ and the same $x^s$ in $(1)$, nevertheless the integral $(1)$ converges only for $\Re(s)>1$.

Comment: the critical difference is that the second integral avoids the singularity at zero (of "order" $\Re s -2$) where $\Re s -1 >0$ is crucial for convergence; at infinity both integrals converge absolutely for all $s$; Titchmarsh book on the subject has the full explanations starting on page 18

Comment: This question seems to overlap https://math.stackexchange.com/q/3412810. Also see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hankel_contour.